# Keyboard shortcut for right-click in current cursor position on OS X? ('Menu Key' on Windows)

Tags: macos, keyboard, mouse, shortcut

On windows computers there is often a key for this. Called the 'Menu Key' [image]

There is also a keyboard shortcut in windows, when the key is missing. `Shift + F10`

A similar request was made [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/119699/how-to-make-right-click-using-keyboard/)  but the question was not sufficiently clear and the answers provided demonstrate how to make a right-click where the mouse ***pointer*** is on the screen, which is not useful.

What we need is a shortcut to make a right-click where the ***cursor*** is on the screen. The same as the windows functionality.

Mouse pointer:

[image: 3]

Cursor:

[4] http://www.gmr-publishing.com/ecards/images/copy-paste_04.gif](http://www.gmr-publishing.com/ecards/images/copy-paste_04.gif)

Comment: But that's exactly what's proposed in the first answer. I've checked with Better Touch Tool and Right Click works where the *cursor* is.

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek  I think the OP is differentiating between the ***cursor (where you type)*** and the ***pointer (where the mouse is)***, which, if is the case, you would need to script moving the pointer to the cursor coordinates first, then simulate the right click.

Comment: @Allan You're right, my bad. I should have read this more carefully.

Answer (score 0):

In researching this particular issue, I ran a accross a particular app called [Shortcat](http://shortcatapp.com/).

You can create a keyboard shortcut to select an element and click or right-click where your **pointer** is.

Note:  the right clicking function that brings up the menu where the ***pointer*** is seems to be OS X convention.

I tried this in Word and One Note for Windows as well as OS X.  In Windows, when you press the "right click key" or simply right click, it will bring up the contextual menu where your cursor is.  In OS X, it will bring up the contextual menu where your pointer is.