# App Keyboard Shortcut for Context Menus?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, pages

In Mac Pages there is a context menu item I use all the time: Look Up "[highlighted word]"

I would like to assign a keyboard shortcut to this menu item. However, because it is non-static (always changing based on highlighted word), I cannot figure out the correct Menu Title. I tried 'Look Up' but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should be a system-wide shortcut  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>D</kbd> 
Hover mouse over word [no need to select it].

Check in System Prefs > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Services > Searching to make sure it's switched on.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think the idea here is to bring the context menu without touching the mouse at all (if you need to move the cursor above the word and then press that combination then you might as well right click the word). This is possible on windows with a dedicated button that brings the context menu at the "insertion point" (i.e., the location the keyboard would print a character if you were to press a letter). For more info https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/119699/159704 and https://superuser.com/a/662464/231377 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/41237/159704

Comment: @HalilSen - Thing is, you can call this under the mouse pointer without any text being pre-selected by key command, but not at the insertion point. They're not linked that way.

Comment: I know that's why I commented

Comment: OP wasn't asking for a Windows equivalent. They asked for a key command, as the answer provides.

Comment: Sure thanks 